# Android - Image Picker, Wrong Image

Tags: android, android-intent, action, media

I am starting a request for an image pick:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType( "image/*" );
intent.setAction( Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT );
startActivityForResult( Intent.createChooser( intent, "Choose"), PHOTO_GALLERY );
```

And getting the data back out in `onActivityResult`:

```
if( resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == PHOTO_GALLERY )
{
  U.log( data.getData() );
  Bitmap bm = ... // built from the getData() Uri
  this.postImagePreview.setImageBitmap( bm );
}
```

When I launch the Intent, I see some folders, such as `sdcard`, `Drop Box`, `MyCameraApp`, and so on.

If I chose a picture from `sdcard`, when I load the preview, it is the completely wrong image. The other folders don't seem to be giving me this problem.

Does anyone know why it'd let me pick one image, then give me the Uri for another?

**EDIT:** Here are some exampled logged `getData()`s:

Good:

`content://com.google.android.gallery3d.provider/picasa/item/5668377679792530210`

Bad:

`content://media/external/images/media/28`

**EDIT:** I'm still having issues, when picking from the sdcard folder of gallery.

Here is a bit more expansion of what I'm doing in onActivityResult:

```
// cursor
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query( selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null );
cursor.moveToFirst();

int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex( filePathColumn[0] );
String filePath = cursor.getString( columnIndex );
cursor.close();

// Cursor: /mnt/sdcard/Pic.jpg : /mnt/sdcard/Pic.jpg
U.log( "Cursor: " + filePath + " : " + Uri.parse( filePath ) );

// "regular" 

// Regular: content://media/external/images/media/28 : content://media/external/images/media/28
U.log( "Regular: " + data.getDataString() + " : " + Uri.parse( data.getDataString() ) );

// Regular 2: content://media/external/images/media/28 : content://media/external/images/media/28
U.log( "Regular 2: " + data.getData() + " : " + data.getData() );


mPostImagePreview.setImageBitmap( BitmapFactory.decodeFile( filePath ) );
mPostImagePreview.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
```

They still set the wrong image. If I go into the Gallery, long press the image, and view its details I get:

```
TItle: Pic
Time: May 2, 2012
Width: 720
Height: 1280
Orientation: 0
File size: 757KB
Maker: Abso Camera
Model: Inspire 4G
Path: /mnt/sdcard/Pic.jpg
```

So, the Gallery is telling me the path is the same as the pick action, and the Gallery is rendering it correctly. So why on earth is it not rendering if I set it from onActivityResult?

Also, this is the code I'm using to fire the Intent now:

```
private void selectPhoto()
{
  Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT );
  intent.setType( "image/*" );
  ( ( Activity )mContext ).startActivityForResult( Intent.createChooser( intent, "Select Picture" ), PHOTO_GALLERY );
}
```

Comment: Is this behavior random? I mean, is there any pattern you see when you repeat the image selection..?

Comment: maybe the thumbnails in the gallery are wrong. this can happend if eg images get deleted because Android reuses the image ids.

Comment: @userSeven7s: Always when I Pick from the Gallery app's sdcard folder.

Comment: @uwe: How do I fix that? Is there a cache to flush or something?

Comment: @uwe: Dude, going to Manage Apps > Gallery > Clear Data did it. It must have had an old thumbnail. Can you add an answer so I can award your bounty?

Comment: @Josh great this solved it :) I added it as answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes the thumbnails in the gallery app can be outdated and show thumbnails for a different image. This can happen when the image ids are reused, for example when an image gets deleted and a new one is added using the same id.

Manage Apps > Gallery > Clear Data  can fix this problem then.

Comment: Thanks again! Unfortunately it seems the system auto assigned the bounty when time ran out the other day, but I have marked yours as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 4):

This is the code to open gallery. However this the same what you have done. Also see the `onActivityResult` code which I used to retrive the selected image.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),  
                       PHOTO_GALLERY);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
switch (requestCode) {
    case PHOTO_GALLERY:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = Uri.parse(data.getDataString());
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(  
                                   getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),   
                                   selectedImageUri);

                this.postImagePreview.setImageBitmap( bitmap);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;`

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

OnActivity Result

```
  @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Other than the slightly different intent, that's literally exactly what I have right now, as noted in my earlier post edit. I did attempt your Intent fire, and it still yields the same result.

Answer (score 3):

try this one

```
 //Put this code on some event 

   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

 startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);

           // When above event fire then its comes to this 
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
              if (resultCode==RESULT_OK && requestCode==1){

                  Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();

                            // Use it as per recruitment 
                    actualBitmap =BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);

              }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public class SelectPhotoActivity extends Activity {

private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
private String selectedImagePath="";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PICTURE); 
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE)
        {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
           // here you can set the image
            }
    }
}

}
```