# Android getting pictures from photo's gallery - error on some devices

Tags: android, image, android-sdcard, mobile-devices

I have a function on my app which I open the photo's gallery and select an image to show in a ImageView. The weird thing is, on my Samsung Galaxy S5, the code work perfectly, but when I try on an ASUS Zenphone, or Motorola Moto X the code just doesn't work and the application crashes.
All the devices has the same Android version (5.0)

Here is my code samples:

**Intent to open photo's gallery:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, IMG_SDCARD);
```

**Activity Result:**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    File file = null;

    if(data != null && requestCode == IMG_SDCARD && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK){
        Uri img = data.getData();

        String[] cols = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(img, cols, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int indexCol = cursor.getColumnIndex(cols[0]);
        String imgString = cursor.getString(indexCol);
        cursor.close();

        file = new File(imgString);

        if(file != null){
            wd.getImage().setResizedBitmap(file, 1200, 700);
            wd.getImage().setMimeFromImgPath(file.getPath());
        }
    }

    if(wd.getImage().getBitmap() != null){
        imageView.setImageBitmap(wd.getImage().getBitmap());
    }
}
```

Would you guys have ever seen something like this?
Could have differences on getting images from the photo's gallery between the different devices?

**EDIT**
This is the log error:

```
01-21 10:34:01.066  30243-30243/com.inthecheesefactory.lab.designlibrary E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.inthecheesefactory.lab.designlibrary, PID: 30243
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65539, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:4904 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.inthecheesefactory.lab.designlibrary/br.com.amais.viumeupet.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char[] java.lang.String.toCharArray()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3559)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3602)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1334)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char[] java.lang.String.toCharArray()' on a null object reference
        at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:179)
        at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:128)
        at br.com.amais.viumeupet.Fragment1.onActivityResult(Fragment1.java:285)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:153)
        at br.com.amais.viumeupet.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:231)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6220)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3555)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3602)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1334)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: do you have your error log?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33938665/android-integrating-gallery-functionality-with-camera-capture/33939277#33939277

Comment: i'll get the error log, and gonna try that sollution @SuhasB

Comment: [Here is answer for your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33938665/android-integrating-gallery-functionality-with-camera-capture/33939277#33939277)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static final int GALLERY_INTENT_REQUEST_CODE = 0x000005;
```

To open Gallery & get path of selected image use following code :

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
 photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
 photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());        
 mActPanelFragment.startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, ActivityConstantUtils.GALLERY_INTENT_REQUEST_CODE);
```

After that you get path in onActivityResult() method

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
(requestCode == ActivityConstantUtils.GALLERY_INTENT_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
try {
            String imagePath = getFilePath(data);
            // TODO: Here you set data to preview screen
    }catch(Exception e){}
}
}

private String getFilePath(Intent data) {
    String imagePath;
    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    imagePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();

    return imagePath;

}
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement that `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` return to you a `Uri` from the `MediaStore`. Even if it does, there is no requirement that your code will give you a path to a file that you have read access to. In your case, `imgString` is `null`, which is not terribly surprising.

Instead, get rid of all of this (including whatever `wd` is) and use an [image-loading library](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/46), like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), that can just take the `Uri` to the image and handle all the loading and resizing for you (on a background thread) and update your `ImageView`.

If you insist upon doing this yourself, fork a background thread, then use `ContentResolver` and methods like `openInputStream()` and `getType()`, along with `BitmapFactory`.