# Not able to save the bitmap image

Tags: android, image, bitmap, save

Here I am not storing the picture that I captured. It is displaying in the image view, but I am trying to save the image, however the image is not displaying in the image view.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1;
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1;
String imgDecodableString;
ImageView iv;
Bitmap bmp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selectImage();
        }
    });
}
public void selectImage() {

    final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery","Cancel" };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
    builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (options[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/CameraImages/example.jpg";
                File file = new File(path);
                Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                //  intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri );

                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            } else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
            } else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {
            bmp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            Log.w("path of image from gallery......******************.........", bmp + "");
            iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }
}else {
        if (requestCode == 2) {

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
            String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
            c.close();
            bmp = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            Log.w("path of image from gallery......******************.........", picturePath + "");
            iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }
    }
}}}
```

> When an adding intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri
>   ); image is saving but not displaying in image view

Comment: Check this this will help you Its working code in my application :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34923702/android-getting-pictures-from-photos-galery-error-on-some-devices/34942980#34942980

Comment: Hi suhas , ur link is for fetching image from gallery actually thats working for me what i want is i need to save the image even when am displaying it in respective image field

Comment: yes I post the answer for saving image.

Comment: you want save image  and  and displaying its imageview?

Comment: Yes saeed i just need it

Comment: ok wait  bro i will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code I have used for Capturing and Saving Camera Image then display it to imageview. You can use according to your need.

You have to save Camera image to specific location then fetch from that location then convert it to byte-array.

Here is method for opening capturing camera image activity.

```
private static final int CAMERA_PHOTO = 111;

private Uri imageToUploadUri;


private void captureCameraImage() {

        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), 
"POST_IMAGE.jpg");

        chooserIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));

        imageToUploadUri = Uri.fromFile(f);

        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, CAMERA_PHOTO);

    }
```

then your onActivityResult() method should be like this.

```
@Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == CAMERA_PHOTO && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if(imageToUploadUri != null){
                    Uri selectedImage = imageToUploadUri;
                    getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
                    Bitmap reducedSizeBitmap = getBitmap(imageToUploadUri.getPath());
                    if(reducedSizeBitmap != null){
                        ImgPhoto.setImageBitmap(reducedSizeBitmap);
                        Button uploadImageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadUserImageButton);
                          uploadImageButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(this,"Error while capturing Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Error while capturing Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } 
        }
```

Here is getBitmap() method used in onActivityResult(). I have done all performance improvement that can be possible while getting camera capture image bitmap.

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(String path) {

        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            final int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 1200000; // 1.2MP
            in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);
            in.close();


            int scale = 1;
            while ((o.outWidth * o.outHeight) * (1 / Math.pow(scale, 2)) >
                    IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
                scale++;
            }
            Log.d("", "scale = " + scale + ", orig-width: " + o.outWidth + ", orig-height: " + o.outHeight);

            Bitmap b = null;
            in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            if (scale > 1) {
                scale--;
                // scale to max possible inSampleSize that still yields an image
                // larger than target
                o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o.inSampleSize = scale;
                b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);

                // resize to desired dimensions
                int height = b.getHeight();
                int width = b.getWidth();
                Log.d("", "1th scale operation dimenions - width: " + width + ", height: " + height);

                double y = Math.sqrt(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE
                        / (((double) width) / height));
                double x = (y / height) * width;

                Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, (int) x,
                        (int) y, true);
                b.recycle();
                b = scaledBitmap;

                System.gc();
            } else {
                b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            }
            in.close();

            Log.d("", "bitmap size - width: " + b.getWidth() + ", height: " +
                    b.getHeight());
            return b;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("", e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Also you ensure that you added all permission in your manifest file

Hope this will Helps you

Comment: Let me know your result

Comment: Hi saeed ur code is working great but i need small help that he image is saving only once next time when i take picture its overlaping the previous image can you tell me how to list it seperately

Comment: its simple you can add timstamp to save image

Comment: File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
              +System.currentTimeMillis()+  "POST_IMAGE.jpg")

Comment: OK bro I am happy to helped you  see you

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
FileOutputStream out = null;
        String filename = getFilename();
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




public static String getFilename() {
        File file = new File(dirPath,image_path+"/Images");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        String uriSting = (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/"+ System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
        return uriSting;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the onActivityResult code and declare the outputFileUri as global...

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {

            BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize=8;
            final Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(outputFileUri.getPath(),options);
            Bitmap photo = bitmap;

                //Log.w("path of image from gallery......******************.........", bmp + "");
                iv.setImageBitmap(photo);

        }else {
            if (requestCode == 2) {

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
                c.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
                String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
                c.close();
                bmp = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
              //  Log.w("path of image from gallery......******************.........", picturePath + "");
                iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            }
        }
    }}
```