# How to overwrite photo file in android

Tags: android, file, android-asynctask, camera, imageview

If I take a picture and save it to a file, it shows up in the ImageView with no problem (picasso). If I then try to overwrite the old image by taking a new picture, it does not work: the old picture keeps showing up. And I don’t know why. Here is my call

```
if (null != photoFile) {
  takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
  auxiliary.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, Constants.REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO);
}
```

Then in onActivityResult I resize the image and then display it (using asyncTask). Again, the first time around it works. But no subsequent picture taking can replace the first picture I took. Any help?

Actually if I close the app (i.e. remove from recent) and then restart the app, then the new photo will show.

Comment: may this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284896/not-able-to-save-the-bitmap-image/35285302#35285302

Answer (score 0):

I got it! I had to call

```
Picasso.with(imageView.getContext()).invalidate(file);
```

since the path is not changing, Picasso does not know that the content is new.